# How to increase the link count for a directory, link count went to 0?

Tags: filesystems, symlink, hard-link, stat, lsof

I have made myself land in this situation, it is a chrooted workspace on my system where I virtualize the entire file system ( so its not actual /var/log ) Is there a way that I can either delete this file completely or increase the link count ? When I delete it, it says, Device or resource busy, but I can't find this inode number 91849100 in lsof. I am not able to figure out what to do next. Please help

```
stat /var/log stat /var/log   File: `/var/log'   Size: 0               Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory Device: 97fh/2431d      Inode: 91849100    Links: 0 Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root) Access: 2013-08-07 04:26:47.231703346
-0700 Modify: 2013-08-07 04:26:47.231703346 -0700 Change: 2013-08-07 04:26:47.231703346 -0700
```

Comment: If you're looking from inside the chroot, I think you may miss processes that aren't chrooted.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you've run out of inodes perhaps? You can use the command `df -i` to see how many you've got, used, and are free.

#### Example

```
$ df -i
Filesystem                        Inodes   IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_grinchy-lv_root
                                 3276800  607937  2668863   19% /
tmpfs                             998436      16   998420    1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda5                         128016      86   127930    1% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_grinchy-lv_home
                                16293888  637520 15656368    4% /home
```